# Javascript global variable when using Scripts.Render MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, global-variables, render

I have an MVC 4 project that utilizes javascript bundling.

In my `_Layout.cshtml` page I have something like this:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts/desktop/modernizr",
        "~/bundles/scripts/desktop/jquery","~/bundles/scripts/desktop/jqueryui",
        "~/bundles/scripts/desktop/jqueryvalidation", "~/bundles/scripts/custom")
```

There are others, but this is just an example.  Within one of my scripts that's called in the custom script I need to reference a global variable that set within the ready function, as shown below:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">                   
     $(function () {            
         //alert('Page is ready!');
         var warning = 10;
         var timeout = 20;   }); </script>
```

Problem is, I always seem to get an error within the method that requires the warning and timeout variables.  Am I missing something obvious (not to me, though!) on how I should create these variables?  Should I `var` them outside the `$Ready`, because the js is loading before the page is technically ready?

Where should the global variable go, if everything is already in a render bundle and there are no script blocks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The `warning` and `timeout` variables aren't global. They've only been defined within the function that you provide to the `$` function.

I'd generally recommend avoiding global variables where possible, but if you really want to create global variables just use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var warning = 10;
   var timeout = 20; 
</script>
```

Or this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       window.warning = 10;
       window.timeout = 20;   
   });
</script>
```

Comment: you advised to avoid global variables. i know that `global variables (or functions) can overwrite window variables`. was that your point?

Comment: @MazdakShojaie Generally, polluting the global scope is bad practice for a number of reasons. Keeping variables local to the scope where they are useful helps to understand code and prevents unexpected behavior like a variable being modified by an unrelated function or accidentally referring to a built-in global property like `Window.name`. The [W3C wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals) has a descent discussion of this, but also be sure to read up on [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules).

Comment: Thank you very much, the `W3c wiki` link was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.

I don't think adding the variables in the Ready page will work.  The functions that require these variables are loaded before the page is 'ready' (per my understanding how this all works), so there are situations on a new page load where the variable will be required but unreferenced.

This is how I'm currently handling it:

I created a new .js file, with the following:

```
    var warning;
    var timeout;
```

Then I created a bundle reference to the file and put it into my @Script.Render stmt in the correct order for scope.  Now, I have my global variables, and it's cleanly implemented into my view code.  Now, I know that I should be passing around variables vs. having them global, but in this case I don't see a major issue.